# Getting Error Access Denied when creating Filtered Lookup in SP2007 List

Tags: 2007, lookup-column

Using WSS SP2007 as a site curator.

List A is a new list.
List B is a resource list with a view showing active Project Managers.

When I go to create a filtered lookup column in List A I immediately get the "Error: Access Denied" after select "filtered lookup" in the new column window.  I do not even see the choices for select the list and view.

I questioned our SharePoint Admins and they believe it's a rights issue but they cannot find the cause.  Any ideas where I can suggest the SharePoint admins to look to fix my rights?

I even went as far as having the SharePoint admins create the filtered lookup for me and it works but I get the same error when edited the field in List Settings.

I am really trying to avoid creating a separate list of PM names and using the standard lookup because I already have that in List B.

There are 7 lists at this time that have a Program Manager drop down and I would like to convert them all to filtered lookup for ease of maintenance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a google search this is most likely related to a persmissions issue though based on the link below it might be specific to a add-on that was used:

http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/discussions/51296

States adding people to "Site Collection Admin" group, tweaking some code, and possible adding permissions to the individual user.  I will pass this along to my people but any additional advice is still welcomed.